# windows - physically print from list of files

Tags: powershell, pdf, printing

I am trying to find a way to physically print all pdf files saved on a server with a specific string in their name "-report" and also created on a specific day. All these files are kept in separate sub-folders withing a single parent directory.
I create many of these reports during the day and would like to be able to print them all at once come end of day.

is this possible using CMD or Powershell?

Comment: The problem that you are probably missing is that you need a RENDERER to print anything.. something that is going to actually interpret the PDF file and send those commands to the printer.  The PDF file format does not belong to Microsoft.  With that said, there are some third party utilities like [PDFtoPrinter](http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/pdftoprinter.html) that can do this job.

Comment: This is absolutely possible.  What have you tried?

Comment: Señor CMasMas, there is no need for a 3rdP thingy to do this. Windows already provided a PDF Printer. If we take the OP at their word, then that `-report` is in the file name, so no need to open the PDF at all. Getting the `DateCreated`, again, is just a file property, not a PDF-specific thing. Now, if the OP is trying to read inside a PDSF< then your point is valid.

Comment: Hi postanote, that is correct. "-report" is in file name. i specified PDF file type because i don't want to accidentally print any other type of document that may have that string in its name.

Answer (score 0):

Still_learning (as we all are)... Yes, you can do this with any scripting language. cmd.exe, VBScript, WMI, PowerShell, Python, whatever.

You say you are, you are printing based on filename and created date. These just file properties, not anything specific to PDF.

Windows has a built-in PDF printer, so, just recursively get the files by date and execute the print command.

All you need is in the PowerShell help files.

```
# Get paramter, example, full and Online help for a cmdlet or function
(Get-Command -Name Get-ChildItem).Parameters
Get-help -Name Get-ChildItem -Examples
Get-help -Name Get-ChildItem -Full
Get-help -Name Get-ChildItem -Online

(Get-Command -Name Out-Printer).Parameters
Get-help -Name Out-Printer -Examples
Get-help -Name Out-Printer -Full
Get-help -Name Out-Printer -Online
```

As for printing files, there are tons of examples all over the web showing how to print files via PowerShell.

['powershell print a file by partial name'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell%20print%20a%20file%20by%20partial%20name%27&va=b&t=hr&ia=web)

['powershell print a pdf file by partial name'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell%20print%20a%20pdf%20file%20by%20partial%20name%27&va=b&t=hr&ia=web)